# Button event when end touch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make voice recorder app. The
recording should start when long touch begins and the
recording must end when user stops the gesture on the button.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *longGesture=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(startrecording)];
```

How can I handle that when the user leaves the button?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See this to find out the correct ways of asking question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in viewDidLoad method

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnButton = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressOnButton:)];
longPressOnButton.delegate = self;
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[btn addGestureRecognizer:longPressOnButton];



- (void)longPressOnButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    // When you start touch the button
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
       //start recording
    }
    // When you stop touch the button
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //end recording
    }
}
```

Also you can try or use the touchEvent concept

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)e {
    // show touch-began state
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)e {

}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)e {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    .....
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)e {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As user3182143 said, using a `UILongPressGestureRecorgnizer` will solve your problem, but if you are interested there is another way using a `UIButton`. No need to add a `UILongPressGestureRecorgnizer`!

From your storyboard, drag an `IBAction` for a `UIButton`. And while you are adding its name, **change the `event` to `Touch Down`**.

Now drag another `IBAction` for the same `UIButton` and while changing its name, change the event to `Touch up Inside` (if it isn't that already).

```
- (IBAction)touchDownButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Start");
}

- (IBAction)touchUpInsideButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"End");
}
```

Handle your recording based on the actions!

Here is a screenshot just in case:

[image]